# Word for a sound of insult-with-a-smile

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, sounds

What is that sound called, when one produces a short demeaning (almost as if looking down upon the other person) sound, which might be followed by a very cunning smile.

Example:

A: The US is pressurizing Iran on genuine grounds. It has no horses of its own in that race.

B: *That Sound*, Are you really that dumb?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Alice: *"The US has no horses of its own in that race".*
>    Bill: (**snorts**) *"Are you really that dumb?".*

...where Google defines [**snort**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20snort&oq=define%20snort&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.3057j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) as...

> an explosive sound made by the sudden forcing of breath through one's nose, used to express indignation, derision, or incredulity.
>    *"he gave a snort of disgust"*

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post.

Comment: I thought the Google definition was the most appropriate for OP's context, but I don't know how to post a direct link to the specific text I get in my first search result. I just posted the address bar contents from my search. I don't know if it'll work for others.

Comment: The intended pragmatics is as described; but the sound is in fact a human speech sound, and has phonetic properties. A _snort_ does have to be (a) ingressive and (b) nasal. Blowing your nose is not a snort. Other than that, the phonosemantics are in line with [other `SN-` words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sn.pdf).

Comment: @John: I don't know the antonym of "ingressive" in this context, but I suppose [harrumph](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=harrumph) would be a common enough noun/verb if we wanted to avoid being "sniffy".

Comment: The antonym is "egressive". Normal speech is egressive lung air. A snort is ingressive pharynx air with open velic nasal channel. If you want to be more precise. There are probly other phonations that would produce a snort; like most non-lexical phonation (think whistling or yodelling), there's enormous individual variation

Answer (score 5):

Wiktionary lists several words as  “representation of the dental click used to show disapproval”:

• *[tch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tch)*, “a representation of the dental click used to show disapproval; tut”
• *[tut](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tut#Interjection)*, “tut tut; an expression of disapproval”
• *[tut tut](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tut_tut)*, “An exclamation of disapproval”, with pronunciation note “IPA: /ǀ ǀ/ (dental clicks). Often the spelling pronunciation IPA: /ˈtʌt ˈtʌt/”
• *[tsk tsk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tsk_tsk)*, “An exclamation of disapproval”, with pronunciation note “IPA: /ǀ ǀ/ (dental clicks). Often the spelling pronunciation IPA: /ˈtɪsk ˈtɪsk/ or IPA: /təsk təsk/”

Answer (score 0):

humph (which I would spell hmph)